# How to transition from one activity to another activity like left to right and right to left in" kotlin"?

Tags: kotlin

As I'm learning Kotlin for Android development, I'm now trying the basic programs like hello world and how to navigate from one activity to another activity , there is no issue in this.

My concern is when I move from one activity to another activity it works fine but I how to  move right to left and left to right

Comment: Provide your code samples

Comment: I dont have kotlin code to move left to right .but i did left to right anim in android

Comment: You mentioned you can move from one activity to another. So as I understood, you want to use this code as a foundation.

Comment: Edit the question and add the snippet there.

Comment: move from one activity to another activity like iOS transition. I am not able to find Anim package in Kotlin. Below is android code                                                       
startActivity(new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class)); overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);